# error 102: Invalide namespace error:http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/2.0

Tags: apache-flex, air, adobe, flexbuilder

I'm trying to create a signed AIR package for an old code of a desktop adobe AIR app.

[image]

It runs on flex sdk 3.5.1 and adobe AIR. I'm clear of errors and when I try to export the release build, I get past the certificate addition section and then I get an error saying "

> error 102: Invalide namespace error:http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/2.0.

I see it is picking up from `appname-app.xml`. But I have adobe AIR installed with version 26. Could anyone tell me what am I missing?

Comment: I don't use flexbuilder (I use flashdevelop for AIR projects and it's been quite a while), but usually this means the version you're targeting doesn't match the namespace you've declared.  try using `26.0` as the last part of your namespace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to download and compile against the 3.5.1 sdk that includes the adobe air 2 sdk OR change the namespace in the app.xml to match the air sdk that you are using now.